# Why are the lights still on in Metropolis in Man of Steel?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

While Zod and Superman are duking it out across Metropolis, you see them destroying building after building. What surprises me is that the lights are on in all of the buildings.

You'd think that with the first building destroyed, it would  trip the main power  breakers across the city -- not to mention major power cables getting ripped out.  There should have been a major power outage in the first few minutes of the fight. In this universe, even one substation blowing out during Sandy took out all of lower Manhattan.

In Metropolis, does each building have its own <strike>Stark reactor</strike> power generator in the basement?

Comment: Unless you happen to be an expert in "power system resilience", I question your competence to assert that there **should have been** a power outage :-)

Comment: Manhattan. Hurricane Sandy. One substation took out half of downtown.

Comment: Taking out a substation is different to bringing down a building.

Comment: Substations aren't buildings?

Comment: Substations are sometimes in buildings, but a building does not necessarily have a substation in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comics, Metropolis is known as "The City of Tomorrow" often because it contains improvements or innovations beyond other present-day equivalents.  Manhattan is over 380 years old.  The fragility and inflexibility of its power grid is a longstanding and known issue difficult to address because its spine has over a hundred years of development on top of it.  Overhauls and modifications demands shutting down streets and creating perpetual gridlock in a densely populated city already just barely able to keep up with its maintenance.  It has taken- literally decades- to install additional subway lines in NYC for similar reasons.

Contrast that against Metropolis.  The city is within the District of Metropolis.  An entirely new Federal District, liberated from the interference of State politics, and built from the ground up with modern urban planning and future-proofing in mind.  Several of the skyline shots we're given reveal a city with skyscraper density rivaling anything in the known world (except, maybe, Gotham from Nolan's other universe).  Even the Metropolis in Superman Returns is dwarfed.

For such a sprawling city to support that much height- and therefore traffic and population density- it must be a brilliant model of efficiency to justify itself and the commute its citizens must partake.

Therefore, it is completely reasonable to presume that Metropolis has modular or redundant power grid that hardens it against isolated catastrophe.

Answer (score 3):

Stark Industries would have to go a long way to export their ARC-reactor to Metropolis... :P

A possible out-of-universe answer might be that it's most likely cheaper to render the city always the same way instead of adding flickering lights - or worse lights in different buildings failing at different times - and having to factor the light path into each shot.

In universe is more problematic:
In the days of the old Superman movies that could have been explained away with the fact that Superman battles around that poor town so often that after him being around a while, all the lighting has emergency back-up power build in, maybe like emergency lights in super-endangered-high-risk-of-earthquake-zones.

Maybe Metropolis is just a city where frequent blackouts do happen and the office buildings downtown are all equipped with backup-generators providing power long enough to 1) protect the data and 2) evacuate the people.

Comment: That's right, forgot Stark was in another universe. :-)

Comment: LexCorp can provide similar services I'm sure :-) Or Queen Industries or WayneTech... ooops right, universe wrong cities.

Comment: Surely both Bruce and Ollie have a business presence in Metropolis. Just because Microsoft is in WA and Apple is in CA, doesn't mean that people in either state are limited to the local product.